# rosbag clock different

Tags: rosbag, clock

When I run command "rosbag play --clock A.bag" and "rostopic echo /clock" two times for catching the simulated clock time, there start time and time duration is not the same, e.g.

**First Time**
**Epoch 1 : secs: 1703157046      nsecs: 583343592**
**Epoch 2 : secs: 1703157046      nsecs: 593441459**

**Second Time**
**Epoch 1 : secs: 1703157046      nsecs: 582122735**
**Epoch 2 : secs: 1703157046      nsecs: 592180827**

As can be seen, there's a difference(nsecs are different) between start time(Epoch 1) and time duration(Epoch 2-Epoch 1),why this happen?Is there a solution to make rosbag replay simulation time totally same?